# why WaitForExit() doesn't wait?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

i am adding Custom Action into my VS2008 setup project (MSI installer).

I am calling a batch file to create database and want to delete those files after. I have WaitForExit() but it will not wait. Why?

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            string tempDir = @"C:\Temp\";
            startInfo.FileName = tempDir + "sybaseDB\\en_AllInOne_installDB.bat";
            startInfo.Arguments = tempDir + "sybaseDB\\";

            try
            {
                Process startDB = Process.Start(startInfo);
                startDB.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //do something?
            }
            finally {
                System.IO.File.Delete(tempDir);
            }
```

no difference with `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true`;
The batch was executed without any problem because it require user input and I input y and n for questions. but that delete action happened before my input. And I have a pause at the end of the batch file. I can watch the process of the batch file going.

**EDIT:**
I tested more than 10 times, it didn't work. After lunch, I put one more waitForExit and a while loop with HasExited check. it will sleep inside the while loop. I found it worked. Then I deleted those extra code, back to one WaitForExit. It seems work now.

Comment: Your `//do something?` exception handler is bad.  If there's an exception when starting the process, you will not know about it.

Comment: will have something there later

Comment: Well, put there something *now* so you *know* whether this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably throwing an exception because you can't execute a .bat file.  You probably intend to execute cmd.exe by giving the .bat file as a command line argument.

Comment: no problem with the batch file. It was launched and I can watch the entire process. It will take couple of seconds to finish.